# How to switch between ROS Hydro and ROS Indigo Version on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed both ROS Hydro and ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 12.04. I want to know how to switch between these versions when I am compiling a catkin workspace in Ubuntu.  I have two catkin workspaces, one of them works with ROS Hydro and the other works with ROS Indigo. So, if I want to do a catkin build of the catkin workspace based on ROS Indigo, then what should I do?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196561/how-to-switch-between-ros-hydro-and-ros-indigo-version-on-ubuntu-12.04?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a new terminal you need to run

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

That will set your current terminal to use Indigo. Be careful that you don't source any other Hydro `setup.bash` files in your `~/.bashrc` file or you might start [overlaying packages](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying), which is probably not what you want to do.

To switch back to Hydro, you need to open a new terminal and run

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-11-04**:
Sourcing a different setup file does not affect previously configured workspaces. You need to wipe the build/devel folder and rebuild the workspace with the different environment.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2014-11-04**:
@ish45 says that he has two separate workspaces, one for each distro. Should he still need to wipe the build/devel folders?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-11-04**:
Sorry, I missed that part. No, then it is not necessary.